# Creating Button for Admins Only MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am creating a Database in Microsoft Access for a school project. I have created a login feature where an employee of a business has a username and password and with this they have a UserAccess of either 1 or 2. 1 is user privileges and 2 is admin privileges.

I managed to make it so that the users cannot access certain forms on the database, however, i have been attempting to make a way so that employees who are users do not have access to certain buttons.

I created a delete button a customer form so it can delete customers. I used a macro to do this. The problem is im not entirely sure on how to go about this to make it available to admins only

Here is the code for my login form:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnLogin_Click()
Dim rs As Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblStaff", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)

rs.FindFirst "UserName='" & Me.TextUserName & "'"

If rs.NoMatch Then
    Me.lblIncorrectUsername.Visible = True
    Me.TextUserName.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
Me.lblIncorrectUsername.Visible = False



If rs!Password <> Nz(Me.TextPassword, "") Then
    Me.lblIncorrectPass.Visible = True
    Me.TextPassword.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
Me.lblIncorrectPass.Visible = False

    TempVars("EmployeeType") = rs!EmployeeTypeID.Value

    If rs!EmployeeTypeID = 2 Then
    Dim prop As Property
    On Error GoTo SetProperty
    Set prop = CurrentDb.CreateProperty("AllowBypassKey", dbBoolean, False)

    CurrentDb.Properties.Append prop
SetProperty:
        If MsgBox("Would you like to turn on the Bypass Key?", vbYesNo, 
        "Allow Bypass?") = vbYes Then
        CurrentDb.Properties("AllowBypassKey") = True
    Else
        CurrentDb.Properties("AllowBypassKey") = False
    End If
End If

DoCmd.OpenForm "Main Menu"
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name

End Sub
```

For creating the way in which buttons only appear to admins I had tried to switch my macro into VBA Code and insert the line of code :

```
if EmployeeTypeID= 2 then
me.btnDeleteCustomer.visible = true
else
me.btnDeleteCustomer.visible = false
end if
```

the finished macro in VBA with the code is:

```
Function Macro1()
If EmployeeTypeID = 2 Then
Me.btDeleteCustomer.Visible = True
Else
Me.btnDeleteCustomer.Visible = False
End If
On Error GoTo Macro1_Err

On Error GoTo 0
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord


Macro1_Exit:
    Exit Function

Macro1_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
Resume Macro1_Exit

End Function
Function Macro1_Sub1()
On Error GoTo Macro1_Sub1_Err

Beep
MsgBox "There is nothing to Delete.", vbOKOnly, ""


Macro1_Sub1_Exit:
    Exit Function

Macro1_Sub1_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Macro1_Sub1_Exit

End Function
```

Comment: FWIW storing passwords in clear-text isn't a secure solution. Consider hashing & salting the passwords and comparing hashed strings instead of the actual passwords.

Comment: In the table i have the field as a hash, i just need to create it so that certain buttons can be access by admins only

Comment: `If rs!Password <> Nz(Me.TextPassword, "")` contradicts this. But whatever.

Comment: The field where the passwords are stored are stored as password so that the field shows ******

Comment: That's just the visual representation of the password textbox. By "field" I was referring to the actual database field where the actual passwords are stored. Having the actual passwords in the database is poor practice, ref. every single data breach since forever. Just saying, that design is not secure. Do what you will with it.

Comment: I could potentially change it down the line but don't think much has to be changed in regard to that for the school project.

Comment: Cool, have fun! If I was teaching that class you'd be getting bonus points for implementing an actually secure solution ;-)

Comment: I probably will change it but at the moment its not something that im focusing on, just need a way around the button situation as nothing i have tried has been working.

Comment: Where is `EmployeeTypeID` declared? I'm expecting it to be some global-scope variable (which anyone can assign by just typing `EmployeeTypeID = 2` in the immediate pane), but I'm not seeing it declared. Is `Option Explicit` specified?

Comment: Option Explicit is specified, EmployeeTypeId is a table called "EmployeeType", with the id's 1 and 2. 1 being for user and 2 for admin privileges

Comment: `EmployeeTypeId` can't be a table (it's a *column* in your `Staff` table in the `Click` handler of the first snippet, and it's a *variable* in `Macro1`). You want to do `If EmployeeTypeID= 2 Then`, so `EmployeeTypeId` needs to be a variable that's declared *somewhere*, and your login form needs to assign to it. If it *is* declared, then you can do `EmployeeTypeId = rs!EmployeeTypeId` after the login is known to be successful, that way `Macro1` will be able to see its value.

Comment: sorry i meant it is in a table*. The table is EmployeeType and inside is the EmployeeTypeId and the Security Level. It is also in my staff table where either staff have a value of 1 or 2 depending on if they are admins or users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach the show / hide code to your form load rather than your macro.

This may help you:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/form-load-event-access

Learning to read the MSDN articles to get what you need done will be of great assistance to you.

Comment: I was wrong, that in fact solved my problem. Such a simple problem, obviously i didnt logically think it through! Thank you for this suggestion. All i had to do was when the form loads if they arent an admin then button disappears. Stupid by my end!

Answer (score 0):

You're close.

You're assigning `TempVars("EmployeeType") = rs!EmployeeTypeID.Value`, but then you're doing this in `Macro1`:

```
If EmployeeTypeID = 2 Then
```

I'm not very familiar with Access, but assuming `TempVars` is some global values collection, replace that with a read on the `TempVars` variable you've written the data into:

```
If TempVars("EmployeeType") = 2 Then
```

Or, simplify the conditional and assign to a Boolean expression:

```
Me.btDeleteCustomer.Visible = (TempVars("EmployeeType") = 2)
```

Also, specify `Option Explicit` at the top of the module that contains `Macro1`: I suspect you have a compile error there, since `EmployeeTypeID` looks like an undeclared variable.

---

**NOTE:** This code demonstrates variable assignments, table column reads and other basic mechanics - it is **in no way** a secure solution. Do not use this or anything like it in a solution that need to be actually secure.

Comment: what i did was added that last line of code and what happens is the buttons appears for admins and disappears for users. However, for some reason now when i click on the form anywhere it is given a prompt to delete the record

Comment: actually the button just disappears now for all types of users. this project will be the death of me

Comment: Reset global scope by typing `End` in the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G), take a deep breath, and bring up the login form again. Setup a watch on the value of `TempVars("EmployeeType")`, from the *Debug* menu.

Comment: Please note that `TempVars` is designed to survive the VBE reset. Therefore to reset the `TempVars`, use `TempVars.RemoveAll`

Comment: I put end in the immediate pane and put a watch on TempVars part, not sure if it is correct or what it does. Here is a gyazo if it helps https://gyazo.com/79e2f8effad60dcccf3c1627deba0dbb

Comment: @Cbrady good. Put a breakpoint (F9) on the first statement of `Macro1`, and then another on the `TempVars("EmployeeType") = rs!EmployeeTypeID.Value` line in the button's click handler; when execution reaches that line, the VBE will stop execution right there and you can hit F8 to execute line by line, and if the watch is correctly setup then you should be able to see the current `EmployeeType` value in the *watches* toolwindow; if that doesn't match what you're expecting, then something else is messing with your tempvars.

Comment: You've been really helpful and I know I'm probably a pain! I have inserted a breakpoint at the first line of macro1() and another in the code for my login form where you asked. But when I'm pressing the play button nothing is happening.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really help much more than that without a TeamViewer session (not happening... sorry!) - good luck!

Comment: I just ran the login form again and signed into a admin account and went through lines of code but it did not go onto the break point where the macro is.

Comment: The code on the login end i think works fine but the one here https://gyazo.com/c65b7236976880b2c5dc14d252789bde seems to cause bother. The part of making the button visible or not seems not automatically make the button invisible at all times yet anywhere on the form that is clicked carries out the function of deleting a record

Answer (score 0):

One should have a Start screen (sometimes called a Switchboard) that is always open when the application is open.  This should have a text box holding the user ID. (visible or not is your call).

Then in the OnCurrent event of any form - one adds VBA to control the visibility of controls (i.e. buttons) based upon the value of the user id.